# Show exposed filter entry with match number

Tags: views

I want to have some view filter like this one for example.

[image]
I want a list of option [a select..] with the number of results they provide.

Can I do this in some way?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with the help of [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

You just need to override the `$form['type']['#options']`

**Example**

An exposed filter with content types and the number of nodes attached to each select option.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form['#id']) {
    case 'views-exposed-form-[YOUR-VIEW-NAME]-page':
      foreach ($form['type']['#options'] as $option => $name) {
        if ($option != 'All') {
          $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) amount FROM {node} n "."WHERE n.type = :type AND n.status=1";
          $result = db_query($query, array(':type' => $option))->fetch();
          $name.= ' (' . $result->amount . ')';
          $form['type']['#options'][$option] = $name;
        }
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

If you don't want to run the query every time when the filter is being displayed, then you need to create a variable with these numbers. The query might be then performed only once, during your module installation, and the variable would be updated only when the node will be created, updated or deleted.

**An example with the custom variable**

Custom function to create or update our custom variable.

```
function update_node_numbers() {
  $node_numbers = array();
  $node_types = node_type_get_types();
  foreach ($node_types as $type => $object) {
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) amount FROM {node} n "."WHERE n.type = :type AND n.status=1";
    $result = db_query($query, array(':type' => $object->type))->fetch();
    $node_numbers[$object->type] = $result->amount;
  }
  // set variable
  variable_set('node_numbers', $node_numbers);
}
```

The function should be fired only during administrative tasks (install module, create, update or delete node)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install.
 */
function YOURMODULE_install() {
  update_node_numbers();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall.
 */
function YOURMODULE_uninstall() {
  variable_del('node_numbers');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert.
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_insert($node) {
  update_node_numbers();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_update.
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_update($node) {
  update_node_numbers();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_delete.
 */
function YOURMODULE_node_delete($node) {
  update_node_numbers();
}
```

Now we can alter the form with the help of our custom variable, without using any query.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form['#id']) {
    case 'views-exposed-form-[YOUR-VIEW-NAME]-[DISPLAY-ID]':
      $node_numbers = variable_get('node_numbers');   
      foreach ($form['type']['#options'] as $option => $name) {
        if ($option != 'All') {
          // some options may have been just created.
          if (!isset($node_numbers[$option])) {
            $node_numbers[$option] = 0;
          }
          $name.= ' (' . $node_numbers[$option] . ')';
          $form['type']['#options'][$option] = $name;
        }
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mmmmh.. In this way if I have 200 filter entry I have to run 200 query every site visit.. 
Do tou think there is a more performant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your usecase.

- Count queries always have heavy impact on performance. But in this usecase it seems to be the right direction.
- If you want to speed this one up, cache the view and its results. But only if the results do not change all the time.
- If you have the actual options of each category in an array, you can make a count(); of that array.
- Create a custom variable (a better table field in db), where the count is always updated when anything changes. And then just query that field with a JOIN. Bad: you have to tell views about your new field (hook_views_data).

Comment: Variables are cached and they are updated there only when a variable is changed, added or deleted. That's why I suggested to use a custom variable that would be created, updated or deleted only during administrative tasks. In my opinion it is not a "Bad" idea. It should improve query performance in this case.

Comment: You´re right. What I meant is, that you have to make an entire module to use a custom table and implement hook_views_data. Just for a simple count.

Comment: Btw. variables should be used for storing settings params and stuff like this.